# Preventing Multiple http calls

Tags: http, promise

I have a function which calls the backend service and get the data and display it in the UI. I am using angular, and this function is in my controller which i am calling from the html. So everytime html gets updated it is making a network call.

I tried to add a controller level variable to check if the call is already in progress if yes return its promise or otherwise call again. Which will prevent same calls repeating even before the first call not finished.

Is there any other way that I can handle it across my project.Becuase the method I have, I have to write for individual functions

my current code as follows

```
var getDataPromise;

function getData() {
    if (getDataPromise) return getDataPromise;


    getDataPromise = $http.get('url').then((response) => {

        return response;
    }).finally(() => {
        getDataPromise = null;
    })
    return getDataPromise;
}
```

I only want to prevent overlapping network calls. becuase data in the server can change from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of preventing Multiple http calls is to cancel the previous http call and you can do that by like this:

```
test.service('testService', function ($http,$q) {
    var canceler;
    var getList = function (data) {

      if (canceler)canceler.resolve();
         canceler = $q.defer();
         return $http.post('www.test.com', data,
                {timeout: canceler.promise});

    };
```

Comment: Again this I have to do for individual functions?